# The implementation of Redux's applyMiddleware

Tags: redux, redux-middleware

My question is why `middlewareAPI` can't use :

```
const middlewareAPI = {
  getState: store.getState,
  dispatch: dispatch
}
```

to replace the definition in the source code as below:

```
export default function applyMiddleware(...middlewares) {
  return (createStore) => (reducer, preloadedState, enhancer) => {
    const store = createStore(reducer, preloadedState, enhancer)
    let dispatch = store.dispatch
    let chain = []

    const middlewareAPI = {
      getState: store.getState,
      dispatch: (...args) => dispatch(...args)   // why not just use `dispatch: dispatch`
    }
    chain = middlewares.map(middleware => middleware(middlewareAPI))
    dispatch = compose(...chain)(store.dispatch)

    return {
      ...store,
      dispatch
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone can tell me the difference ? Thanks.

Comment: did you get any error by doing the first code?

Comment: If you use `dispatch` in middleware, the `dispatch` points to the original `store.dispatch`, instead of `dispatch` with middleware chains. That's why it uses a closure to point to the variable dispatch .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a somewhat complicated combination of JS variable scoping/hosting, and needing to ensure that the passed-in dispatch method actually points back to the start of the middleware chain.

Please see the newly-added (and not yet published) [Redux FAQ entry on why `applyMiddleware` uses a closure](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/faq/DesignDecisions.md#closure-dispatch) for more details.